# Handle #Error in SSRS with missing data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm writing a report in SSRS 2008 R2, and I have a field that sometimes contains no value, ie. NULL. I just want to display the value, and for populated entries, this is fine. The problem is, I can't get rid of the #Error in my report if it's a null entry!

I've tried handling the field with multiple expressions, and none of them work.

I've tried

```
=Fields!Example.IsMissing
```

but it returns false, meaning that SSRS doesn't think the field is missing. The value itself

```
=Fields!Example.Value
```

gives an #Error. I've tried

```
=iif(IsError(Fields!Example.Value), 0, Fields!Example.Value)
=iif(Fields!Example.Value is nothing, 0, Fields!Example.Value)
```

all of which still give me #Error! Also, if I do this:

```
=IsNothing(Fields!Example.Value)
```

it returns false, so it doesn't think it's nothing. Frustrating! Any suggestions on what else I should try?

Comment: Ah thanks! I feel like an idiot... I've been doing `Cdbl` on the values, and removing the convert fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `=Fields!Example.Value` gives you an error then you are encountering a deeper problem.

Normally SSRS will treat a true `null` similar to an empty string, and will produce a blank cell. Sounds like you have some sort of formula processing this that is actually generating the `#error`/exception.